# C# The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: c#, namespaces, types, .net-assembly, directive

I have a problem that has been driving me nuts.

I have 2 ASPX pages in which the parent use Server.Transfer() function. The parent is called Submit.aspx whereas child is called Review.aspx

In Submit.aspx.cs, I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Contacts_Submit : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Review_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("Review.aspx", true);
    }

    /* 
     * Sequence of functions that will server as a Get functionality that will
     * return the text inside each textbox.
     * These information will be used by "Review.aspx" to validate the
     * information given by the user before final submission takes place.
     */
    public string GetFirstName { get { return FirstName.Text; } }
    public string GetLastName { get { return LastName.Text; } }
    public string GetAddress { get { return Address.Text; } }
    public string GetCountry { get { return Country.SelectedValue; } }
    public string GetProvince { get { return Province.SelectedValue; } }
    public string GetCity { get { return City.Text; } }
    public string GetZipCode { get { return ZipCode.Text; } }
    public string GetWorkPhone { get { return WorkPhone.Text; } }
    public string GetMobilePhone { get { return MobilePhone.Text; } }
    public string GetFax { get { return Fax.Text; } }
    public string GetEmail { get { return Email.Text; } }
    public string GetCompany { get { return Company.Text; } }
    public string GetWebsite { get { return Website.Text; } }
    public string GetRelationship { get { return Relationship.SelectedValue; } }
}
```

Whereas on the Review.aspx.cs, I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Contacts_Review : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(PreviousPage != null)
        {
            Contacts_Submit prevpage = PreviousPage as Contacts_Submit;
            //FirstName.Text = PreviousPage.GetFirstName;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I declare "`Contacts_Submit prevpage = PreviousPage as Contacts_Submit`". The system is giving me an error that says "The type or namespace name 'Contacts_Submit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

I am a beginner in both ASP.NET and C#, can anyone help me with this? Thank you SOOO MUCH.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just want

```
Contacts_Submit prevpage = PreviousPage as Contacts_Submit;
```

instead of

```
Contacts_Submit prevpage = PreviousPage as System.Data.DataSet Contacts_Submit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Contacts_Submit is type of Page and **not in any way related to Dataset**, so your cast is invalid.
remove that and it should be fine

Comment: Sorry for not updating the code. Actually I did use both ways with the System.Data and also without it. But it still does not work. This is really confusing